# How to use delete on cascade in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, cascade

I have a 'Roles' table:

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->string('name')->unique();
$table->text('description')->nullable();
```

and a 'Roles_Users' table:

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->integer('role_id')->unsigned()->index()->foreign()->references("id")->on("roles")->onDelete("cascade");
$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index()->foreign()->references("id")->on("users")->onDelete("cascade");
```

When I run such a line:

```
Role::where('name','someString')->delete();
```

only the related row in the Roles table is deleted, and related rows in the Roles_Users table aren't. what is the solution?

Comment: To this kind of thing, I really prefer to create the foreign keys and set then "Cascade". You'll have a better performance and for example, if you need to delete records directly via SQL or access your database in another app, your data will retain their integrity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend that you create a "foreign key" constraint for this case (as others mentioned). Also because this is a many-to-many relationship, you can use `detach()` method on your Eloquent model (if you sat the relations correctly in your `user` and `role` models)

```
$user = App\User::find(1);

// Detach all roles from the user...
$user->roles()->detach();
```

You can relate to the documentation for [more details](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#inserting-many-to-many-relationships).

Comment: Many thanks! here the real solution:
`$role=Role::where('name','someString')->first();
$role->users()->detach();
$role->delete();`

Answer (score 4):

Try to apply `$table->index(['role_id', 'user_id'])` and foreign keys after creating columns. So Your code will look like

```
Schema::table('role_users', function($table){
    $table->increments('id') ;
    $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned() ;
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()
});
Schema::table('role_users', function($table){
    $table->index(['role_id', 'user_id'])
}) ;
Schema::table('role_users', function($table){
    $table->foreign()->references("id")->on("roles")->onDelete("cascade");
    $table->foreign()->references("id")->on("users")->onDelete("cascade");
}) ;
```